# Set value based on select

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Im a newbie for code. Now i want to set value on the 'Nama Lengkap' field based on select value of the 'Nomor Induk Siswa' select box without click anything first. Maybe someone can help me to get sample code. Thanks for your help.
[image]

```
<div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-2">
                                        <label for="projectinput1">Nomor Induk Siswa<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <select id="nis" name="nis" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-title="Jam Senin" value="<?php echo set_value("nis"); ?>">
                                                                    <option value="none" selected="" disabled="">-- NIS --</option>
                                                                    <?php
                                                                        if ($nisnya) {
                                                                            foreach($nisnya as $row){
                                                                        ?>
                                                                                <option value="<?php echo $row->kode; ?>"><?php echo $row->kode; ?></option>
                                                                        <?php
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    ?>
                                        </select>
                                        <?php echo form_error('nis'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-2">
                                        <label for="projectinput2">Nama Lengkap</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="projectinput2" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Lengkap Siswa" name="name" value=""  readonly="readonly">
                                        <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: some one can help only if you provide something to work on. Add the code not an image

Comment: No body will give you code out of the box for your solution, you need to try something first, tell us what you have done and what kind of error you are facing.

Comment: I've just post my view code. I want to get value of name based on nis value without press button. Hope i can get a sample code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```js
$('#nis').change(function() {
  var nis_value = $(this).val();
  console.log(nis_value);
  $('#projectinput2').val(nis_value);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="nis" name="nis" class="form-control">
<option value="none" selected="" disabled="">-- NIS --</option>
<option value="S0001">S0001</option>
<option value="S0002">S0002</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="projectinput2" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Lengkap Siswa" name="name" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0):

it was simple

```
<script>
   $("#nis").change(function(){
       $("#projectinput2").val($(this).val())
   })
 </script>
```